# setting actionscript textarea color to black

Tags: actionscript-3, textarea, background-color

I have some simple actionscript 3 code which compiles and runs without error but doesn't do anything. I just want to change the bacground color to black (or transparent). How can this be done?

```
myTextArea.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x000000");
```

I've tried the color argument without quotes and as "black" but nothing seemes to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but it should be enough to change your code to:

```
myTextArea.textField.opaqueBackground = 0x000000;
```

See this link on SO, if you need more help:

[How do I change the colours of a textarea in actionscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174986/how-do-i-change-the-colours-of-a-textarea-in-actionscript)

Comment: Thanks that works! One more question though. How do I get rid of the border as well? I actually found out how to skin the component by double clicking on it, but don't see anything for the border settings there.

Comment: Try this: `myTextArea.textField.border = false;`. If you want to change the border color you can do this: `myTextArea.textField.borderColor = 0xFFCCFF;`.

Comment: 2 for 2! Thanks so much for the help. It's been hard finding good documentation on flash.

Comment: Happy to help. This is the ActionScript reference, always keep it close: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/